# On Redux: How can I change the state of a boolean within an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Normally I see stuff like this on a Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  thisIsBoolean: false,
};

const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.CARD_SELECTED](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      thisIsBoolean: !state.thisIsBoolean,
    };
  },
};

export default createReducer(initialState, handlers);
```

Action:

```
export const booleanExample = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.CARD_SELECTED,
});
```

But I need to do something like this now:
Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  stepOneCardSelected: [
    { index: 0, isDone: false },
    { index: 1, isDone: false },
    { index: 2, isDone: false },
    { index: 3, isDone: false },
  ],
};

const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.CARD_SELECTED](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      stepOneCardSelected: action.payload.stepOneCardSelected,
    };
  },
}
```

Action:

```
export const stepOneCardSelectedAction = stepOneCardSelected => ({
  type: ActionTypes.CARD_SELECTED,
  payload: { stepOneCardSelected },
});
```

So I need to do something to return the state and toggle the `isDone` property within `stepOneCardSelected`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map through your `selectedCard` in state and toggle `isDone`

```
const initialState = {
  stepOneCardSelected: [
    { index: 0, isDone: false },
    { index: 1, isDone: false },
    { index: 2, isDone: false },
    { index: 3, isDone: false },
  ],
};

const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.CARD_SELECTED](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      stepOneCardSelected: state.stepOneCardSelected.map(({index,isDone})=>({index,isDone: !isDone}))
    };
  },
}
```